# Implementing interface with inner interface

Tags: java, interface

I want to implement an interface which has inner interface. I have problem with overriding setter method.
Here is draft of my problem:

Interfaces hierarchy:

```
public interface A {
    public interface B {}
    public void setBs(List<B> list);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class AImpl implements A {
    private List<BImpl> listOfBs;
    public static class BImpl implements B {}
    @Override
    public void setBs(... list) { listOfBs = list }
}
```

What should be the type of `setBs(... list)` method's parameter? `List<? extends B>` doesn't override superclass's method.

Comment: method signature should be the same, so `List<B>`, you could change the signature interface to `List<? extends B>` to use an implementation of B

Comment: Why not declare `listOfBs` as `private List<B> listOfBs`? `listOfBs.add(new BImpl())` would still work normally.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. In my real problem classes A and AImpl are in different namespaces and BImpl is called just B and this confused me (and eclipse with imports).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by fantarama, signature should be `public void setBs(List<B> list)`.

If you're getting the error in your IDE or build framework, make sure your java compiler and target versions are set correctly.

Comment: With this change alone, there is a compiler error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<A.B> to List<AImpl.BImpl>`.

Comment: Agreed, you would also need to change the variable to `private List<B> listOfBs` as you mentioned.